# Autoplay a matplotlib FuncAnimation jsthml element

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm writing code that will be displayed in Google Colab. Colab requires you to use `HTML` function before displaying. This is an example code (from [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html)):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

fig = plt.figure()


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    return im,

HTML(animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True).to_jshtml())
```

This works except you have to click the "play" button for it to play. As shown below:

[image: example image]

Is it possible to generate jshtml such that it will play immediately when box is rendered, as if it's clicked by a human? Note that the code needs to work in Google Colab, which in my experience is slightly more limiting than usual Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the code to click "Play" after display

```py
# this is from your code above
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)

# display animation and click play (the 6th button)
display(HTML(anim.to_jshtml()))
Javascript('document.querySelector(".anim-buttons > button:nth-child(6)").click()')
```

Here's [a working notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IMEhN-UI9GZb6bLoB3ip7Rc0SVTmlHLu).

Comment: This worked at first, but if another animation is already playing, it doesn't seem to autoplay new cells with this javascript. I.e. if you go and pause the previous cell, then re-run the cell with this Javascript code, then it works again. Do you know why that might be the case? Should it be a separate question?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is my first time trying it. You cannot call it across cells, though.